# Gamedev related magazines

Tags: education

Do you know any gamedev related magazines ? 
I only know http://www.gdmag.com/ and http://www.gamasutra.com/ .

I also know http://ffdmag.com/ ,there's texts about flash (sometimes related to games)

Comment: I'm pretty sure those are the only ones...

Comment: Interestingly the latest issue of the IEEE magazine had articles on GameDevelopment.

Comment: I just subscribed to gdmag yesterday and am pleasantly surprised. As a programmer, I already got my money's worth back from some of the articles in there.

Answer (score 3):

Besides Game Developer Magazine from UBN TechWeb and [Develop](http://www.develop-online.net/) from Intent Media, you could find a game developer magazine in [DEVMAG](http://devmag.org.za/). This website is not frequently updated comparing with the first two but it provides free archived PDFs to read and you could reach issue 1 to 29.

Answer (score 2):

Gamasutra is the online companion to Game Developer Magazine, both are UBM TechWeb publications but for whatever reason, the original online content and reprints go to [Gamasutra.com](http://www.gamasutra.com), while the [gdmag.com](http://www.gdmag.com) website basically just serves as an online table of contents for the current print issue.

As far as I know Game Developer Magazine is the only print magazine that targets game developers specifically, although there are a few additional online resources like [GamesIndustry.biz](http://www.gamesindustry.biz/) and [GameDev.net](http://www.gamedev.net/), which is a great site with a bit more of an indy/hobbyist bent but definitely a great resource with plenty of participants from industry.

Answer (score 2):

There is also Develop, at [develop-online.net](http://develop-online.net) .

Answer (score 2):

[AltDevBlogADay](http://altdevblogaday.com/) is also sometimes interesting.

Answer (score 2):

There is [indiegamemag](http://www.indiegamemag.com/) as well

Comment: I couldn't find a sample at the website. Does this magazine only contain interviews/reviews/previews (and other similar content) or does it also contain technical game development articles like gdmag?

Answer (score 0):

There's also [Big Bytes and Small Nibbles](https://www.bigbytesmagazine.com.au)

It contains a mix of reviews, design-focused interviews, and the occasional essay on an aspect of game design.